# Generic Points to the Italians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, math-history

When I first learned algebraic geometry, I naturally wiki-ed the subject and there was a line there that said the old school Italians used the notion "generic points without any precise definition."

Now that I know what a generic point is, I am curious as to **how did the Italians think about a generic point and/or what their intuition about it was** and **what kind of results did they prove using this notion**.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I remember seeing this discussed here before, and with some good references to the literature.  Let me snoop around and see if I can find that.

Comment: Likely [Motivating Example for Algebraic Geometry/Scheme Theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/motivating-example-for-algebraic-geometry-scheme-theory) is the discussion I was recalling.  It has four highly upvoted Answers, plus links to other material, but the introduction of "generic point" by Italian geometers is not fully explained.

Comment: Most likely, a generic point was literally just an arbitrary point drawn from a dense open subset, or something thereabouts.

Comment: In complex algebraic geometry, there is a notion of "k-generic point" for a subfield $k$ of $\mathbb C$. It is defined as a point $p \in V(I)$ such that every polynomial $f \in k[X]$ with $f(p)=0$ is in the ideal $I$, hence $f$ vanishes on all of $V(I)$. See the first pages of Mumford's book "Algebraic Geometry I; Complex Projective Varieties".