# "Drawing a Picture" of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Atiyah/Macdonald's commutative algebra book asks the reader to draw pictures of the prime spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}$ in exercise 1.16. I worked through it on my own, figured out what the space looks like as a set and where the open/closed sets are, but when I did some research to check my work I found the following picture:[image]

What exactly is the squiggly line supposed to represent? is it meant to be the ideal $(0)$? That makes a vague bit of sense to me, as the closure of (0) is the entire space, but it contradicts the fact that (0) is a single point in the prime spectrum. Another source said to draw $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ as a curve passing through the ideals $(2),(3),(5),\ldots$ and a separate point off to the side to represent $(0)$, but again I don't get how drawing a curve helps clarify the structure of the space. Why not draw it as a discrete set of points and leave out the curve?

Edit: Here's another guess I just came up with: If we put the finite-complement topology on the real line and then create a quotient space by identifying every point that is not a prime positive integer as one point and call it (0), do we get $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$? If this is the case it would definitely help justify the drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(0)$ is the generic point. It is a single point, in some sense, "nowhere in particular" (quoting Vakil). A way to think of it is that closed points are actual points, and generic points are "fat/fuzzy" points (quoting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942/meaning-of-closed-points-of-a-scheme))

The generic point is drawn as going through all of the other points because the closure of the generic point is the entire space.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. Was I right that the quotient space I described and the Zariski topology on Spec(Z) coincide? I'm trying to come up with a few different angles to understand the space.

Comment: Yes I think so, since the topology on $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ is the intersection of the cofinite topology and the particular point topology.

Answer (score 3):

I really like Yuri Manin's way of describing how points and generic points build up affine schemes. In this sense curves in $\mathbb{C}[T_1, C_2]$ have closed points but also generic points that sit on a "lower level". These generic points in turn sit above the generic point $(0)$.

For $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ it would be points sitting on a plane with the generic point below them, pretty much the two lower levels of the picture below.

$\hskip2in$[image: C]

Comment: Did you make the above picuture? if not, could you tell me where it came from?

Comment: @glimpser it's from Introduction to the Theory of Schemes by Yuri Manin.